# Get JSON representation of Django model

Tags: python, json, django

Let's say I have a Django model

```
class Book(models.Model): 
     title = models.CharField()
     author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
     is_on_loan = models.BooleanField()
```

How do I get the JSON representation of the `Book`? I could easily write something like

```
import json

def get_json(self):
    json_rep = {}
    json_rep['title'] = self.title
    json_rep['author'] = self.author.full_name
    json_rep['is_on_loan'] = self.is_on_loan
    return json.dumps(json_rep)
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called serializing. There are django native serializers, you can read about them in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/), but the basic usage is

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", YourModel.objects.all())
```

That said, Django serializers have some limitations that might or might not cause problems for you.

If you are using or considering using Django REST Framework, it has excellent, flexible serializer/deserializer architecture. There are other serializing libraries out there that you might want to google for.

Comment: The link no longer works, here is an up to date link; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a better way, use the built-in [Django JSON serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization)

```
from django.core import serializers
json_data = serializers.serialize('json', Book.objects.all())
```